# Encrypt EC2 Snapshot using AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2

I am trying to encrypt an unencrypted EC2 snapshot using AWS Java SDK. Here's how it works:

```
1. we need to copy the unencrypted EC2 snapshot because we can't make a change in already existing snapshot.
2. while copying, we need to set encryption as encrypted and create it.
3. After creating the encrypted snapshot, delete the unencrypted snapshot.
```

this is how I do it using AWS Java SDK:

```
 public static void encryptSnapshots(Ec2Client ec2, String snapshotId, String region, KmsClient kms){
        DescribeSnapshotsRequest describeSnapshotsRequest = DescribeSnapshotsRequest.builder().snapshotIds(snapshotId).build();
        DescribeSnapshotsResponse describeSnapshotsResponse = ec2.describeSnapshots(describeSnapshotsRequest);
        KeyUsageType keyUsageType = KeyUsageType.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT;
        CustomerMasterKeySpec customerMasterKeySpec = CustomerMasterKeySpec.SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT;
        OriginType originType = OriginType.AWS_KMS;
        CreateKeyRequest createKeyRequest = CreateKeyRequest.builder().keyUsage(keyUsageType).customerMasterKeySpec(customerMasterKeySpec).origin(originType).build();
        CreateKeyResponse createKeyResponse = kms.createKey(createKeyRequest);
        String kmsId = createKeyResponse.keyMetadata().keyId();
        for(Snapshot snapshot: describeSnapshotsResponse.snapshots()){
            if(!snapshot.encrypted()){
                try{
                    CopySnapshotRequest copySnapshotRequest = CopySnapshotRequest.builder().sourceSnapshotId(snapshot.snapshotId()).sourceRegion(region).destinationRegion(region).kmsKeyId(kmsId).encrypted(true).copy().build();
                    CopySnapshotResponse copySnapshotResponse = ec2.copySnapshot(copySnapshotRequest);
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5);
                    DeleteSnapshotRequest deleteSnapshotRequest = DeleteSnapshotRequest.builder().snapshotId(snapshotId).build();
                    DeleteSnapshotResponse deleteSnapshotResponse = ec2.deleteSnapshot(deleteSnapshotRequest);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the issue with the above code is that the newly encrypted snapshot gives status as `unavailable`

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the keyID while copying the snapshot and by that, it is working.
Changed code:

```
public static void encryptSnapshots(Ec2Client ec2, String snapshotId, String region, KmsClient kms){
        DescribeSnapshotsRequest describeSnapshotsRequest = DescribeSnapshotsRequest.builder().snapshotIds(snapshotId).build();
        DescribeSnapshotsResponse describeSnapshotsResponse = ec2.describeSnapshots(describeSnapshotsRequest);
        KeyUsageType keyUsageType = KeyUsageType.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT;
        CustomerMasterKeySpec customerMasterKeySpec = CustomerMasterKeySpec.SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT;
        OriginType originType = OriginType.AWS_KMS;
        CreateKeyRequest createKeyRequest = CreateKeyRequest.builder().keyUsage(keyUsageType).customerMasterKeySpec(customerMasterKeySpec).origin(originType).build();
        CreateKeyResponse createKeyResponse = kms.createKey(createKeyRequest);
        String kmsId = createKeyResponse.keyMetadata().keyId();
        for(Snapshot snapshot: describeSnapshotsResponse.snapshots()){
            if(!snapshot.encrypted()){
                try{
                    CopySnapshotRequest copySnapshotRequest = CopySnapshotRequest.builder().sourceSnapshotId(snapshot.snapshotId()).sourceRegion(region).destinationRegion(region).encrypted(true).copy().build();
                    CopySnapshotResponse copySnapshotResponse = ec2.copySnapshot(copySnapshotRequest);
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5);
                    DeleteSnapshotRequest deleteSnapshotRequest = DeleteSnapshotRequest.builder().snapshotId(snapshotId).build();
                    DeleteSnapshotResponse deleteSnapshotResponse = ec2.deleteSnapshot(deleteSnapshotRequest);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```